# roboguice replace Activity with own implementation

Tags: android, roboguice

Is there a way to replace the default Activity class with own implementation extending from this class using roboguice?

For instance an activity like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{...}
```

would replace the default Activity class and would become the base activity for all other derived activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The easiest way is to have your base activity extend from RoboActivity.

Eg.

```
class MyBaseActivity extends RoboActivity { ... }
```

And then have all of your activities extend from MyBaseActivity.

However, if for some reason you don't wish to extend from RoboActivity, you can easily add injection to your own activities by doing the following:

```
class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
    }

    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        RoboGuice.getInjector(this).injectViewMembers(this);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [RoboActivity's source](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActivity.java) for more details.  As long as you don't need events, the changes required are quite simple.